# I am scraping the bet3000 livescore sports website through scrapy-splash which has javascript enabled site which give me the error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

**This the spider file**:

'from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from ..items import GameItem

```
class Splash1Spider(Spider):
    name = 'scrapy_splash_1'
    start_urls = ['https://www.livescore.bet3000.com']
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url = url, callback = self.parse, args = {"wait":15})

    def parse(self, response):
        item = GameItem()
        for game in response.css('.tournament.filterable.table-block.status_result
```

**The output is **:

```
base) danish-khan@danishkhan-Latitude-E6430:/media/danish-khan/New Volume/Web_scraping/scrapy_splash/scrapy_splash_1/scrapy_splash_1$ scrapy crawl scrapy_splash_1 
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.0.1 started (bot: scrapy_splash_1)
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.7 (default, May  7 2020, 21:25:33) - [GCC 7.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Linux-5.4.0-47-generic-x86_64-with-debian-bullseye-sid
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'scrapy_splash_1',
 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapy_splash_1.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapy_splash_1.spiders']}
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: aff4870d4448e4b9
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-11-27 21:45:50 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy_splash/request.py:41: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function to_native_str. Use to_unicode instead.
  url = to_native_str(url)

2020-11-27 21:46:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.livescore.bet3000.com via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2020-11-27 21:46:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-11-27 21:46:06 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

I cann't understand that why this error happens i check the css seleectors but cann't worked

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your code. Either of the two things is happening:

1. You are getting an incorrect or not completely rendered response.
2. Your selector is incorrect.

What you can do is place a breakpoint before your for loop and see if the response actually contains the data that you are trying to scrape.

Comment: breakpoint i don't understand just give me explanation.

Comment: There are no errors in your code but your response does not contain the elements that you are looking for. Try saving your response's body to an html file and then you can check that html file if you don't want to add debug using breakpoints.